# Ember.js Evented Controller triggering an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, coffeescript, evented-io

I am trying to trigger an event from an Ember.js controller so the listening views can update themselves.  Here is the Coffeescript.

```
window.CMS.EdmController = Ember.ObjectController.extend Ember.Evented,
  actions:
   save_edm: ->
     postData = $('#edm_form').serialize()
     $.ajax(
       url: 'cms2/update_edm',
       type: 'POST',
       data: postData
       )
       .done ->
         console.log(@)
         @trigger('saveEdmSuccessful')
```

It fails with an error Object #Object has no method trigger.  The @ in the .done function refers to the jQuery post object and not the controller.

How do I get the reference to the parent controller object from inside a jQuery callback?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did try to compile your Coffeescript and ended up getting the following code as output:

```
window.CMS.EdmController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(Ember.Evented, {
  actions: {
    save_edm: function() {
      var postData;
      postData = $('#edm_form').serialize();
      return $.ajax({
        url: 'cms2/update_edm',
        type: 'POST',
        data: postData
      }).done(function() {
        console.log(this);
        return this.trigger('saveEdmSuccessful');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

And the solution to the problem you are facing is not related to ember.js, but the way Javascript closures work. A solution to the above problem would be:

```
window.CMS.EdmController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(Ember.Evented, {
  actions: {
    save_edm: function() {
      var postData;
      postData = $('#edm_form').serialize();
      return $.ajax({
        url: 'cms2/update_edm',
        type: 'POST',
        data: postData
      }).done($.proxy(function() {
        console.log(this);
        return this.trigger('saveEdmSuccessful');
      },this));
    }
  }
});
```

Notice how I've replaced your `.done` handler from a function call to a proxy call. This makes sure that when the callback is executed, the context is updated to reflect the current `this`.

To understand further about the behaviour of `this` in JavaScript, [read this article](http://unschooled.org/2012/03/understanding-javascript-this/).

For your reference, here is the CoffeeScript equivalent of my solution:

```
window.CMS.EdmController = Ember.ObjectController.extend Ember.Evented,
  actions:
   save_edm: ->
     postData = $('#edm_form').serialize()
     $.ajax(
       url: 'cms2/update_edm',
       type: 'POST',
       data: postData
       )
       .done(
          $.proxy ->
            console.log(@)
            @trigger('saveEdmSuccessful')
          @
       )
```

Comment: Sunny

Fantastic help.  Thanks.  As I read your comment I realized Coffeescript has a different method invocation for class context.

.done: => instead of .done: -> would call the method in the class context.

I will try both and update in a short while.

Thanks again.

Comment: Sunny, both approaches worked.

$done: => executed the method in the class context.

Comment: Great, so you taught me something new too. :)